# Combine two spark udf issue

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, udf

I'm using Spark 1.6 with scala; I have to compute the duration which is the difference between end time and start time.
I've tried this:

```
val msc3 = rddsql.withColumn("Duration",($"EndTime")-($"StartTime"))
```

I want to add another condition: when the end time and the start time are equal, the duration should be set to 1 instead of 0.
How to do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `UDFs` at all, you can simply do it using `when` and `otherwise`

```
rddsql.withColumn("Duration",when($"EndTime" === $"StartTime", 1).otherwise($"EndTime" - $"StartTime"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it with 'Case When' and SparkSQL

```
rddsql.createOrReplaceTempView("rddsql")
spark.sql("select CASE WHEN (EndTime-StartTime = 0) THEN 1 ELSE EndTime-StartTime END as Duration from rddsql") //spark is SparkSession
```

Comment: thank you; but as i mention i'm using spark 1.6 ( i don't have spark session)

Comment: @ZiedHermi you can use SQLContext.